# how can i make a pop up menu in sprite kit swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a pop up menu for a game, what's the best way to make it? it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: here come the down votes

Comment: He is right! What have you tried, in what way is that not working, etc.!? We are no coding monkeys for you.

Answer (score 7):

I'll give you a high level explanation

Just create a new `sknode` or `skspritenode` with `zPosition` of `50` or something so its above everything else, and have child nodes in it for buttons, etc. Each node can have a `touches began/ touches ended` event so you can detect touches.

also don't forget to set:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

and then each button (node) can have a texture for what you want the button to look like.

then on clicking the menu button, you can add this menu node to the parent node (the SKScene presumably)

Comment: how would you temporarily disable the abilty to touch nodes underneath?

Comment: not sure, put a big transparent node on top of them so they're not reachable maybe